# Upgrading custom iOS plugins from Cordoba 1.7 to 2.1, how can I find out why they are never loaded?

Tags: xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ios6

I've got my plugins converted, or so I think, and registered in Cordova.plist. The method signatures are correct, according to [this guide](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md). Nothing has changed on the js side, yet they don't load and just fail silently. Cordova itself is working, onDeviceReady is firing, but my plugins just never get executed. Everything worked fine with 1.7...

I'd like some help to get started on figuring out where they are supposed to be loaded and/or called from js on the obj-c side. Where can I set a breakpoint in the Cordova source to see why it's not executing my plugin?

Where should I begin to look?

Answer (score 0):

I just did exactly this migration. All I can say is that it worked for me if you follow the steps. You also need to follow the steps from the 1.9>2.0 migration.

Answer (score 0):

Since Cordova 2.0, the framework had big changes.

Maybe is better you implements again using the 2.0 rules and, after, only override selector signature. Thus you learn how do plugin in new versions, updating your Cordova skills. :)

Single big change between 2.0 and 2.1 (for plugins)

> Support a new plugin method signature (old signature is deprecated):
>
> The new signature is:
>   - (void) myMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
>
> The old (deprecated) signature is:
>   - (void) myMethod:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;